# How to SUM elements within a list of objects in python

Tags: python

I am trying to sum (plus other maths operations) a specific attribute of my list of objects and I do not know how to do it.

A example of what I am trying to do is:

```
my_list = [
             {
               'brand': 'Totoya',
               'quantity': 10
             },
             {
               'brand': 'Honda',
               'quantity': 20
             },
             {
               'brand': 'Hyundai',
               'quantity': 30
             }
           ]
```

I want to SUM all the 'quantity'. Is it possible without a loop?
using collections? Counter?

```
Output = 60
```

Comment: total = sum([item['quantity'] for item in my_list])

Comment: Thanks @ChrisDoyle..!!!

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I think your answer is the most pythonic so you should post it as an answer so Jonathan can accept it.

Comment: this answer already covers the same as my comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/59413341/1212401

Comment: Or a generator expression instead of a list comprehension - `total = sum(item['quantity'] for item in my_list)`.

Answer (score 4):

as the input is:

```py
my_list = [
             {
               'brand': 'Totoya',
               'quantity': 10
             },
             {
               'brand': 'Honda',
               'quantity': 20
             },
             {
               'brand': 'Hyundai',
               'quantity': 30
             }
           ]
```

You can loop over it as this:

```py
counter = 0
for i in my_list:
    counter += i['quantity']
print(counter)
```

or in oneliner:

```py
print(sum(i['quantity'] for i in my_list))
```

Comment: No need for the intermediate list `[...]` in the `sum`

Answer (score 1):

Python contains good functions for functional programming.

```py
my_list = ...

# Select the quantities from my_list
quantities = map(lambda x: x['quantity'], my_list) 
# Computes the sum of quantities
total = sum(quantities)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative way to do this

```
from operator import itemgetter

getter = itemgetter('quantity')
sum(map(getter, my_list))
```